# Pass array through class constructor using C++ variadic templates

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constructor, variadic-templates

I would like to modernize a small mathematical library using new C++ paradigms (I have a C++17 compiler). In specific, I need to pass an array to a class through constructor.

This is the "classical" old way I used. It works

```
class Vector {
public:
    long double* elements;
public:
    Vector(int size, long double *array) {
        elements = new long double[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            elements[i] = array[i];
        }
    };

    virtual ~Vector() {
        delete []elements;
    }

};

int main() {
    long double array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    Vector vector = Vector(10, array);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << vector.elements[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, I tried to change Vector class with what I have understood about variadic templates and parameter pack. It doesn't work

```
class Vector {

public:
    long double* elements;
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Vector(Args... args){
        constexpr int size = sizeof...(Args);
        elements = new long double[size]{args...};
    }
};

int main() {
    long double array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    Vector vector = Vector(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << vector.elements[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error returned by compiler is

> error: cannot convert ‘long double*’ to ‘long double’ in initialization
>
> ```
>     elements = new long double[size]{args...};
> ```

What am I doing wrong?
Further, I'm wondering if it is possible to use a std::array instead of raw array, both either inside main method and in Vector class.

Comment: Termplates are expanded at compile time, it won't replace `array` with its initialization list.

Comment: Use `std::array` instead of these awful c-style arrays please!

Comment: Using `std` together with a class named `Vector` and a variable named `vector` is probably an extremely poor idea.  (See `std::vector`)

Comment: You are using `new` which is a very poor choice. You also do not obey the rule of zero so your `Vector` will break in even simple cases. Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: @TheDude Ok, it seems like a good idea. In fact, I do not want to use c-style. But, how can I pass a _std :: array_ through constructor without using to loop to initialize the inner _std :: array_? Does it exist a different way than templates and parametric pack?

Comment: @Squerut `std::array` already has a copy constructor. So you don't need to do that yourself. A nested `std::array<std::array<double,inner_size>,outer_size>` should work just out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I would give you a general advice:
I guess you want to encapsulate your own logic into the vector. 
The standard library vector is very advanced and you should use it, instead of loosing time to write your own low-level code. You could concentrate more on the logic you need.

Your could define your own vector and still use the advantages of the std::vector for constructing your Vector objects.
For example with inheritance:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector : public std::vector<int>
{
   // here comes the implementation of your interface.
}
```

or composition:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
private:
    std::vector<T> elems;
}
```

In the case of composition you'd have to define the constructors you need.

In both cases you could then use your own Vector as follows:

```
Vector<double> vec1(10);         // construct vector with 10 double's each = 0
Vector<double> vec2(10, 5);      // construct vector with 10 double's each = 5
Vector<double> vec3{1,2,3,4};    // using initializer list
Vector<double> vec4(somecontainer.begin(), somecontainer.end());   // construct vector by copying elemts from some other container
```

etc.

As you see with std::vector you'are getting all the benefits you need for constructing your own Vector object.

Comment: I like the second approach you used (I prefer incapsulation to inheritance) and the way you create a Vector object passing directly N values to constructor. In my case, since I don't need to add elements to the inner class container after the Vector is constructed, is it possible to use _std::array_ and **not** _std::vector_? In both cases, now I am able to delete in my Vector class either the **new** and the **destructor**. But, how can I populate the inner Vector class _std::array_ container without using for loop inside constructor **but** using incapsulation?

Comment: std::array is an aggregate type, which means it has no constructors. I've provided you 2 examples for inheritance and composition using std::array with initialization without for loop (when that was your question): 
 https://wandbox.org/permlink/af2xWXg9AOkm1G1h

Comment: Thanks a lot for your further examples! After making some tests (and having some problems with _std::array_ size) I decided to follow your suggestion to use **std::vector with incapsulation**, as described in main your answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

To pass an array like that variadic templates are not the solution. Variadic templates are used to pass *N* numbers of parameters to a class/function. Yet you are passing only one parameter!

I would suggest you to

I suggest you tu use array references, which are available in all C++ versions:

```
class Vector {
public:
    long double* elements;
public:
    template<std::size_t size>
    Vector(long double (&array)[size]) {
        elements = new long double[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            elements[i] = array[i];
        }
    };

    virtual ~Vector() {
        delete []elements;
    }
};
```

By the way, if you can, use vector. I highly doubt this custom vector class is as efficient as `std::vector` (no geometric growth or optimized copy and move)

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition of

```
 template<typename... Args> Vector(Args... args);
```

You want to use this constructor in this way:

```
 Vector vector = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0);
```

It is possible, if you sightly modify your definition of the constructor to:

```
template<typename... Args>
Vector(Args... args){
    constexpr int size = sizeof...(Args);
    elements = new long double[size]{static_cast<long double>(args)...};
}
```

Please note such kind of use is **not** good practice, you should normally use `std` containers and avoid `new` operator.

Comment: I would like to not use new operator; so _std_ containers are welcome. I'm wondering if it is possible to use _std::array_ inside my Vector class instead: the main ideas are to **remove destructor** and to **not use for loop** in constructor to fill the inner _std::array_ container

Comment: `std::array` needs to know the number of elements at compile time, if you put it directly in your class, your class need to have a template parameter for its size. But all in all, why not use `std::vector` ? It serves all the requirement you mentioned. Normally you don't need to make a class named `Vector`.

Comment: The class is named Vector because I use it incapsulated in 2DVector, 3DVector and 4DVector classes. So Vector would be a general purpose class, then specialized by others. I am asking about _std::array_ because I need just a container that is not able to change its size after it is created and filled. It is not a problem to have a class with a template parameter where I pass the size. Do you think _std::vector_ is better than _std::array_ in this case too?